# c# screen bounds are not correct

Tags: c#, forms, screen

I have an issue with the screen size. I would like to get the size of my screen from my Windows Form Program but when I do :

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;
```

> bounds.Width = 1536  instead 1920 (my resolution screen).

Could you help me please ?

Comment: 1920 / 1536 = 1.25.  That is a magic number, be sure to declare your app to be dpiAware so you don't have to be lied to.

Answer (score -1):

```
Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

does this help? Your code returns the correct screen size for me

```
int count = Screen.AllScreens.Count();
for (int itr = 0; itr < count; itr++) {
    Console.WriteLine("The width of screen {0} is {1}", itr, Screen.AllScreens[itr].Bounds.Width);
}
```

The above code will loop through all your monitors

Comment: It's the same. I have the same result.
It's  due to the DPI value (or Zoom) of 125%. (1536 * 1.25 = 1920)

Thanks for you answer =)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
```

Maybe youre selecting the wrong monitor? Because Screen is the main lib used to get screen res.

Comment: It's the same. I have the same result.
It's  due to the DPI value (or Zoom) of 125%. (1536 * 1.25 = 1920)

Thanks for you answer =)